# vueJS [Vue warn]: The computed property "title" is already defined in data

Tags: vuejs2

```
<script>
import alertStore from '../stores/alert';
Vue.component('alert', require('vue-strap').alert);

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            show: alertStore.state.show,
            title: alertStore.state.title,
            msg: alertStore.state.msg,
            type: alertStore.state.type
        }
    },
    created () {
    },
    computed: {
        title () {

            return alertStore.state.title;
        },
        msg () {
            return alertStore.state.msg;
        },
        type () {
            return alertStore.state.type;
        },
        show () {
            return alertStore.state.show;
        },
        duration () {
            return alertStore.state.duration;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        dismissAlert: function () {
            this.$store.dispatch('dismissAlert', {title: '...'});
        },
    }
}
```

How does the namespace work in Vue? Is both data keys, computed return object keys, and all components object keys will be added to the this instance?

So if I override this. I get some error like:

[Vue warn]: The computed property "title" is already defined in data.
[Vue warn]: The computed property "show" is already defined in data.
[Vue warn]: The computed property "type" is already defined in data.
[Vue warn]: The computed property "msg" is already defined in data.

How can i resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need to use computed properties? Or why do you define the component's members in "data" and "computed"?

Comment: actually this code done by another developer and i am new with the vuejs. I have read vueJS tutorial but not finding any solution why add data in data object. If i remove return from data object no error come and still my template not showing.

Vuejs dev tool show me computed loading : false

Any idea what can i do.

Comment: post code for your template.

Comment: Please check below, i have pasted my full template code.

Answer (score 1):

Vue binds all properties in the data method to the root of the instance. It also does this for computed properties, and methods, so you must use different names to avoid naming conflicts.

The main problem in the code you posted is that you have naming conflicts with every data property. In fact, because you are using a Vuex store, you don't need the data properties at all, just the computed properties.

This is also not the best way to use Vuex stores. The general recommendation is to use `mapGetters` as documents [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html).